# Add the contents of an array together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the size of each food in the menu and add the size of all of them together and display the total size of the menu in the console. Please help. My code does not work.

The desired result => total  size : 225

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];

const totalSize = () => {
    const b = parseFloat(menu.size);
    const result = b.forEach(itemA, itemB => itemA + itemB);
    console.log(`total  size : ${result}`)
}
totalSize();
```

Comment: You want `reduce`, not `forEach`.

Comment: How do they sum up to be 225??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menu` is an array, it has no `size` property. You need to access the `size` property of each element.

You need to use `reduce` to combine operations between elements, not `forEach`.

When an arrow function takes multiple arguments, they have to be enclosed in parentheses.

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];

const totalSize = () => {
    const result = menu.map(item => parseFloat(item.size)).reduce((total, item) => total + item);
    console.log(`total  size : ${result}`)
}
totalSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];

const totalSize = () => {
    const result = menu.reduce((sum, item) => sum + parseFloat(item.size), 0);
    console.log(`total  size : ${result}`)
}
totalSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Soda', price: 3.12, size: '4oz', type: 'Drink' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Beer', price: 6.5, size: '8oz', type: 'Drink' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Margarita', price: 12.99, size: '12oz', type: 'Drink' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Pizza', price: 25.1, size: '60oz', type: 'Food' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Kebab', price: 31.48, size: '42oz', type: 'Food' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Berger', price: 23.83, size: '99oz', type: 'Food' }
];

const totalSize = () => {
    let result = menu.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc += Number(item.size.slice(0, -2));

        return acc;
    }, 0);
    console.log(`total  size : ${result}`);
};
totalSize();
```